# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key link

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ipad

My app is crashing, any thoughts please? I am parsing the xml in my code, here is the code.

if i removed this line it works fine
                [listItem setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
Thanks

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
            NSLog(@"found channel");
            app.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
            listItem = [[NewsList alloc] init];
            listItem.title = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];
            listItem.description = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"description"];

        }



    }


    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        if (!currentElementValue) {
            currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];

        }
        else
            [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }


    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
            return;
        }

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
            [app.listArray addObject:listItem];
            listItem = nil;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"element name = %@", elementName);

            [listItem setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        }

        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
```

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: @trojanfoe, that question looks different, in my case i placed breakpoint and it works for 4,5 fields and then it crashes.
 NSLog(@"element name = %@", elementName);
[listItem setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
i can see the element and it comes here multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Your object `listItem` is of class `NewsList`. Since you get the error when you use `setValue:forKey:`, this class `NewsList` either has no property with name `elementName` and instance variable `elementName` or `_elementName`, or the setter method `setElementName:` has not been implemented.
Please check that you have set up your property correctly, e.g. using `@property` and `@synthesize`.